# jQuery html(text) parsing via ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, forms

So I have a form which is sent to a python script via ajax. The python script is outputting an entire HTML page which includes content type doctype and all that.

Now I need to insert a part of the response text from the python script, a div element, into a div on the current page.

How do I parse the response text and strip away all of the unnecessary junks like doctype and header?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to change the python script so it only produces the bit that you want? That could be a lot more efficient than doing it in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I get what you are saying. But no unfortunately, because the python file needs to be viewed directly, too.

Comment: Could you make the python script take an argument, so instead of GETting '/foo.py' you're GETting '/foo.py?div=id-of-div', then have a bit of logic in foo.py to handle it?

Comment: ya..i did some adjustments. It's best to change up the python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success function you have to filter the result like this:

```
success: function(r){
    var divContent = $(r).filter('#myDiv').html();
}
```

I created a working fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/vd2LC/).

That's the solution for your question, but jimw is right with his comment about changing the script  to output just the content, that would be the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax function you probably have a success function or something similar where the data variable is outputted, if the returned data is valid HTML, just parse the output with a filter, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.mysite.fun/html.py"
//using the new .done() function, works the same with .success
}).done(function ( data ) { 
    var element = $(data).filter(function() {
                      if (this.id=='IdOfMyDiv') return this;
                  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZTmPv/2/)

Comment: Great, we've been working on the exact same solution at the same time ;)

Comment: thanks a lot! although I went with changing the python in the end, but this will definitely be helpful for future projects